# How to install WiFi

Tags: esp32

This is about PlftformIO extension to VSCode.

**Code:**

```
/*********
  Rui Santos
  Complete project details at http://randomnerdtutorials.com  
*********/

// Load Wi-Fi library
#include <WiFi.h>

// Replace with your network credentials
const char* ssid = "linksys";
const char* password = "goskomstat";

// Set web server port number to 80
WiFiServer server(80);

// Variable to store the HTTP request
String header;

// Auxiliar variables to store the current output state
String output26State = "off";
String output5State = "off";

// Assign output variables to GPIO pins
const int output26 = 26;
const int output5 = 5;

// Current time
unsigned long currentTime = millis();
// Previous time
unsigned long previousTime = 0; 
// Define timeout time in milliseconds (example: 2000ms = 2s)
const long timeoutTime = 2000;

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(115200);
  // Initialize the output variables as outputs
  pinMode(output26, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(output5, OUTPUT);
  // Set outputs to LOW
  digitalWrite(output26, LOW);
  digitalWrite(output5, LOW);

  // Connect to Wi-Fi network with SSID and password
  Serial.print("Connecting to ");
  Serial.println(ssid);
  WiFi.begin(ssid, password);
  while (WiFi.status() != WL_CONNECTED) {
    delay(500);
    Serial.print(".");
  }
  // Print local IP address and start web server
  Serial.println("");
  Serial.println("WiFi connected.");
  Serial.println("IP address: ");
  Serial.println(WiFi.localIP());
  server.begin();
}

void loop(){
  WiFiClient client = server.available();   // Listen for incoming clients

  if (client) {                             // If a new client connects,
    currentTime = millis();
    previousTime = currentTime;
    Serial.println("New Client.");          // print a message out in the serial port
    String currentLine = "";                // make a String to hold incoming data from the client
    while (client.connected() && currentTime - previousTime <= timeoutTime) {  // loop while the client's connected
      currentTime = millis();
      if (client.available()) {             // if there's bytes to read from the client,
        char c = client.read();             // read a byte, then
        Serial.write(c);                    // print it out the serial monitor
        header += c;
        if (c == '\n') {                    // if the byte is a newline character
          // if the current line is blank, you got two newline characters in a row.
          // that's the end of the client HTTP request, so send a response:
          if (currentLine.length() == 0) {
            // HTTP headers always start with a response code (e.g. HTTP/1.1 200 OK)
            // and a content-type so the client knows what's coming, then a blank line:
            client.println("HTTP/1.1 200 OK");
            client.println("Content-type:text/html");
            client.println("Connection: close");
            client.println();
            
            // turns the GPIOs on and off
            if (header.indexOf("GET /26/on") >= 0) {
              Serial.println("GPIO 26 on");
              output26State = "on";
              digitalWrite(output26, HIGH);
            } else if (header.indexOf("GET /26/off") >= 0) {
              Serial.println("GPIO 26 off");
              output26State = "off";
              digitalWrite(output26, LOW);
            } else if (header.indexOf("GET /5/on") >= 0) {
              Serial.println("GPIO 5 on");
              output5State = "on";
              digitalWrite(output5, HIGH);
            } else if (header.indexOf("GET /5/off") >= 0) {
              Serial.println("GPIO 5 off");
              output5State = "off";
              digitalWrite(output5, LOW);
            }
            
            // Display the HTML web page
            client.println("<!DOCTYPE html><html>");
            client.println("<head><meta name=\"viewport\" content=\"width=device-width, initial-scale=1\">");
            client.println("<link rel=\"icon\" href=\"data:,\">");
            // CSS to style the on/off buttons 
            // Feel free to change the background-color and font-size attributes to fit your preferences
            client.println("<style>html { font-family: Helvetica; display: inline-block; margin: 0px auto; text-align: center;}");
            client.println(".button { background-color: #4CAF50; border: none; color: white; padding: 16px 40px;");
            client.println("text-decoration: none; font-size: 30px; margin: 2px; cursor: pointer;}");
            client.println(".button2 {background-color: #555555;}</style></head>");
            
            // Web Page Heading
            client.println("<body><h1>ESP32 Web Server</h1>");
            
            // Display current state, and ON/OFF buttons for GPIO 26  
            client.println("<p>GPIO 26 - State " + output26State + "</p>");
            // If the output26State is off, it displays the ON button       
            if (output26State=="off") {
              client.println("<p><a href=\"/26/on\"><button class=\"button\">ON</button></a></p>");
            } else {
              client.println("<p><a href=\"/26/off\"><button class=\"button button2\">OFF</button></a></p>");
            } 
               
            // Display current state, and ON/OFF buttons for GPIO 27  
            client.println("<p>GPIO 5 - State " + output5State + "</p>");
            // If the output27State is off, it displays the ON button       
            if (output5State=="off") {
              client.println("<p><a href=\"/5/on\"><button class=\"button\">ON</button></a></p>");
            } else {
              client.println("<p><a href=\"/5/off\"><button class=\"button button2\">OFF</button></a></p>");
            }
            client.println("</body></html>");
            
            // The HTTP response ends with another blank line
            client.println();
            // Break out of the while loop
            break;
          } else { // if you got a newline, then clear currentLine
            currentLine = "";
          }
        } else if (c != '\r') {  // if you got anything else but a carriage return character,
          currentLine += c;      // add it to the end of the currentLine
        }
      }
    }
    // Clear the header variable
    header = "";
    // Close the connection
    client.stop();
    Serial.println("Client disconnected.");
    Serial.println("");
  }
}
```

**Error:**

```
 *  Executing task: platformio run 

Processing nodemcu-32s (platform: espressif32; board: nodemcu-32s; framework: espidf)
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Verbose mode can be enabled via `-v, --verbose` option
CONFIGURATION: https://docs.platformio.org/page/boards/espressif32/nodemcu-32s.html
PLATFORM: Espressif 32 (6.0.1) > NodeMCU-32S
HARDWARE: ESP32 240MHz, 320KB RAM, 4MB Flash
DEBUG: Current (cmsis-dap) External (cmsis-dap, esp-bridge, esp-prog, iot-bus-jtag, jlink, minimodule, olimex-arm-usb-ocd, olimex-arm-usb-ocd-h, olimex-arm-usb-tiny-h, olimex-jtag-tiny, tumpa)
PACKAGES: 
 - framework-espidf @ 3.50000.0 (5.0.0) 
 - tool-cmake @ 3.16.4 
 - tool-esptoolpy @ 1.40400.0 (4.4.0) 
 - tool-ninja @ 1.7.1 
 - toolchain-esp32ulp @ 1.23500.220830 (2.35.0) 
 - toolchain-xtensa-esp32 @ 11.2.0+2022r1
Reading CMake configuration...
LDF: Library Dependency Finder -> https://----.ly/configure-pio-ldf
LDF Modes: Finder ~ chain, Compatibility ~ soft
Found 0 compatible libraries
Scanning dependencies...
No dependencies
Building in release mode
Compiling .pio/build/nodemcu-32s/src/main.o
src/main.c:7:10: fatal error: WiFi.h: No such file or directory

**************************************************************
* Looking for WiFi.h dependency? Check our library registry!
*
* CLI  > platformio lib search "header:WiFi.h"
* Web  > https://registry.platformio.org/search?q=header:WiFi.h
*
**************************************************************

    7 | #include <WiFi.h>
      |          ^~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
Archiving .pio/build/nodemcu-32s/esp-idf/app_trace/libapp_trace.a
Indexing .pio/build/nodemcu-32s/esp-idf/app_trace/libapp_trace.a
Archiving .pio/build/nodemcu-32s/esp-idf/app_update/libapp_update.a
Indexing .pio/build/nodemcu-32s/esp-idf/app_update/libapp_update.a
Compiling .pio/build/nodemcu-32s/bootloader_support/src/bootloader_clock_init.o
Compiling .pio/build/nodemcu-32s/bootloader_support/bootloader_flash/src/bootloader_flash.o
Compiling .pio/build/nodemcu-32s/bootloader_support/src/bootloader_mem.o
*** [.pio/build/nodemcu-32s/src/main.o] Error 1
====================================== [FAILED] Took 2.12 seconds ======================================

 *  The terminal process "platformio 'run'" terminated with exit code: 1. 
 *  Terminal will be reused by tasks, press any key to close it.
```

**ini:**

```
; PlatformIO Project Configuration File
;
;   Build options: build flags, source filter
;   Upload options: custom upload port, speed and extra flags
;   Library options: dependencies, extra library storages
;   Advanced options: extra scripting
;
; Please visit documentation for the other options and examples
; https://docs.platformio.org/page/projectconf.html

[env:nodemcu-32s]
platform = espressif32
board = nodemcu-32s
framework = espidf
lib_deps = arduino-libraries/WiFi@^1.2.7
```

**Library has been installed:**

```
michael@michael:~/Documents/PlatformIO/Projects/blink$ pio pkg install --library "arduino-libraries/WiFi@^1.2.7"
Resolving nodemcu-32s dependencies...
Library Manager: WiFi@1.2.7 is already installed
```

How can I resolve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't "install wifi" separately. It's part of the Arduino framework for the ESP32 and it depends on other parts of the Arduino framework. It's not meant to be used separately.

Your `platformio.ini` file specifies ESP-IDF as the framework to use when building your program. ESP-IDF has its own WiFi API. If you're using ESP-IDF, [use its WiFi functions](https://docs.espressif.com/projects/esp-idf/en/latest/esp32/api-guides/wifi.html).

The Arduino framework is built over ESP-IDF, so you can call some ESP-IDF functions from Arduino programs. You cannot, however, call Arduino functions from an ESP-IDF program as ESP-IDF knows nothing about Arduino.

If you want to use Arduino functions, build an Arduino program by setting the framework in your `platformio.ini` file to be `arduino`.

```
framework = arduino
```

Basically, pick one framework and stick with it. Don't try to mix Arduino functions into your ESP-IDF program.